# const struct { x } vs struct { const x}

Tags: c++, struct, constants

This is a rather simple question, but somehow difficult to find a simple answer for.

In C++, what is the difference between an (edit) const-modified struct variable, and a(edit:) non-const  struct variable, but with the struct having all-const members? :

```
typedef struct mystruct {
    const int x;
} t1;
const t1 s1;
```

vs

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
} t2;
const t2 s2;
```

? (If the answer is "the same as for classes", then please either explain it for classes or link to the explanation.)

Comment: -1 for not even trying to compile the code.

Comment: @JesseGood: The code was not a complete statement, of course it would not compile. But it could be completed into a complete, compilable statement (see [sftrabbit's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20704183/1593077)). Anyway, modified the question to have a compilable statement. Please consider removing your -1.

Comment: @einpoklum The question has been edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `const struct`. You may have seen something like this:

```
const struct {
    int x;
} y;
```

This is a declaration of a variable `y` with struct type. The variable `y` is `const`, not the struct. You can think of it as similar to:

```
struct mystruct {
    int x;
};

const mystruct y;
```

without giving the struct type a name.

Comment: There's also `struct {int x;} const y;`, which I prefer over the first one. I think it's reasonably clear that the `const` applies to the object in that case.

Answer (score 5):

There's *effectively* very little difference between the two objects `a` and `b` below:

```
struct A
{
   int x, y;
};

struct B
{
   const int x, y;
};

const A a;   // (plus initialiser)
B b;         // (plus initialiser)
```

<sup>(You know, of course, that *other* instances of `A` may not be `const`-qualified and then you have an obvious difference.)</sup>

You can't access the members any differently in the one case than in the other. But:

1. You *will* have to ensure that you initialise the members, in both cases (which I haven't done here);
2. `const`-qualifiying the *type* (rather than the members) affects reference-binding:

   ```
   void foo(A& a);
   void foo(B& b);

   int main()
   {
      const A a;
      B b;

      foo(a);  // Error!
      foo(b);  // OK
   }
   ```

   The same is true, of course, if you use a pointer instead of a reference. The `const` context only spreads to calling code when it's applied to the *type* rather than encapsulated within the members.

Comment: BTW, thanks for not beating me up.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming

```
const struct mystruct1 {
    int x1;
    int x2;
} s1;
```

and

```
struct mystruct2  {
    const int x1;
    int x2;
} s2;
```

For `s1` you should not assign values to any members.

For `s2` only the member `x1` should not be assigned a value. One is free to do so for `x2`.

---

To get closer to your example, one could do:

```
typedef const struct mystruct1 {
    int x1;
    int x2;
} S1;

typedef struct mystruct2 {
    const int x1;
    int x2;
} S2;

S1 s1;
S2 s2;
```

For `s1` and `s2` here the same rules apply as above.

---

**Upate**:

Referring your question literally (implying the corrections as by my examples), there is no practical difference between the two construct in terms constantness of the value they carry.

Comment: In your examples, only some of the members are const in the non-const struct, and some aren't, which was not what I was asking about. Of course these two constructs (excuse the pun) are different.

Comment: Umm, I know you wrote a nice and detailed answer, but the bottom bit is the answer to my updated question, so would you mind leaving just that part so that I can accept? :-)